# Schema aware XQuery

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery, zorba

Currently I'm using Eclipses XQuery plugin [xqdt](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT) with the XQuery engine [Zorba](http://www.zorba.io/).

I would like the XQuery engine to "type check" the correctness of my XPath expressions, e.g. if the schema defines videos/video is allowed, but videos/pictures isn't, the interpreter should warn that the latter XPath expression is invalid.

I've tried to follow the [Schema-Aware Queries and Stylesheets](http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema_aware.html) tutorial, but I can't get it to work. My code examples use the sample [video.xml](http://www.stylusstudio.com/examples/videos.xml) and the sample [video.xsd](http://www.stylusstudio.com/examples/videos.xsd) from the tutorial.

My first, stripped down example of theirs results in an type error:
import schema default element namespace "" at "videos.xsd";

```
1   import schema default element namespace "" at "videos.xsd";
2
3   declare variable $input as schema-element(result) := doc('videos.xml')/*;
4   for $v in $input/videos/video
5   return $v
 ...\XQqueryProject\videos.xq>:3,1: type error [err:XPTY0004]: 
element(result, xs:untyped) can not be treated as type schema-element(result)
```

Playing with types, using element instead of schema-element doesn't warn me about my misspelled video2 path and doesn't print anything:

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "videos.xsd";

declare variable $input as element(result) := doc('videos.xml')/*;
for $v in $input/videos/video2
return $v
```

**Q:** Could someone provide me with a minimal working example where $input/videos/video2 fails?

**Update:**
I've added namespaces to the [videos.xsd](http://pastebin.com/yDsJD9pX), the [videos.xml](http://pastebin.com/E63jmWH4) and changed the import schema to

```
import schema default element namespace "myVideos" at "videos.xsd";
```

, but without success.

Comment: Looks like your xml is in no namespace (which is different from no prefix). Perhaps best to tie both xsd and xml to a namespace uri, and refer to namespace using a prefix in your XPath. Not sure though whether schema-awareness includes validation of XPath statements, within XQDT at least..

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm going to test this. Regarding XQDT: I don't care if xqdt shows a 'compile time' error, but I would like Zorba to report this when the query is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither XQDT nor Zorba support static validation of XPath expressions wrt. schemas. There is/was quite some research happening around that topic but (afaik) non of them have made it into a product, yet.

For example, you could get in touch with the guys over at http://wam.inrialpes.fr/websolver/ to see what the status of this project is.